# HTML "a" tag query, how it is being redirecting?

Tags: html

I am new to HTML. I am checking other websites to understand how others implement.
My question is based o the below tag.

```
<a class="list_title" href="Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart">Provincial Family Violence Treatment Program</a>
```

When I click it is directing to `https://www.albertahealthservices.ca/findhealth/Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart`

How is this possible? How is the href string appended with `"https://www.albertahealthservices.ca/findhealth/"`

Edit: The current url is `https://www.albertahealthservices.ca/findhealth/results.aspx?type=service&id=25&locationCity=Calgary&radius=all#contentStart`
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `href` doesn't have a full url, it will just add the `Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart` to the end of the current url.

So if the website is `test.com/test`, and you clicked that button, you would be redirected to `test.com/test/Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart`

However, if the `<a>` tag had the attribute `href="/Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart"`, and the current website was `test.com/test`, you would be redirected to `test.com/Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart`

You can find out more at: https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 1):

The URL you have in the `href` of your `<a> tag is *relative* because it does not start with a slash`/`for`http(s)://`.

Based on your question I would assume that the page that contains this `<a>` tag is located in this folder:
`https://www.albertahealthservices.ca/findhealth/`

If you start the `href` value with a slash `/` like this:
`<a class="list_title" href="/Service.aspx?serviceAtFacilityId=1108532#contentStart">Provincial Family Violence Treatment Program</a>`

Then the browser will end up at this address:
`"https://www.albertahealthservices.ca/Service.aspx"`

---

**To further show how your relative path works:**

If you were on a page located here:
`https://www.example.com/my/odd/path/`

Then your URL in the `href` would end up here:
`https://www.example.com/my/odd/path/Service.aspx`

---

If you were on a page located here:
`https://www.example.com/`

Then your URL in the `href` would end up here:
`https://www.example.com/Service.aspx`

Comment: If you think my answer sucks enough to downvote it, please let me know why so I can fix it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't downvote. But your answer gives me good idea. Thanks